# How to make gridView clickable

Tags: android, image, gridview, directory

I am working on gridView with the aim that fetch the images from a particular folder in SdCard and populate them into GridView. I have write this code mention below but it is not clickable, I am able to fetch the images and upload them into gridview but when I am clicking on the images, it is not working. Please have a look and tell me what mistake I am doing here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        ArrayList <String> itemList = new ArrayList <String> ();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        void add(String path) {
            itemList.add(path);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }

            Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            return imageView;
        }

        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            Bitmap bm = null;
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            return bm;
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
                } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }
    }

    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/camtest/";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[]files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                String prompt = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prompt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: please set myOnItemClickListener to your grid view
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);

Answer (score 0):

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);

 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
   //try this code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this code,like that.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //try this code
}
});
```

Comment: Thanx Pakash, it was a stupid mistake seriously. thnx a lot. 
Prakash, how can I make these images visible .. means I want to make those image enlarge after click. can u please help me in this??

Comment: enlarge image means? in another activity or same activity?

Comment: use this idea, may help yours, In your gridview_main xml create the relativelayout width and height in fillparent and use the imageview in that layout. intially the relativelayout set visiblity gone ,then  your click any images, set the rl visible and corresponding the image set in imagview,then rl set backgroung transparent.try this .hope you help this.

Answer (score 0):

you have created listener  `myOnItemClickListener` but you didn't register it to `gridview.`

this is your listerner:

```
OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                String prompt = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prompt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };
```

set your `myOnItemClickListener` listener to`gridview.`

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
YOUR_GRID_VIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
     {

     }
});
```